# Web Host Updates Whole Site instead of Only The UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, jquery, updatepanel

I'm having some problem finding the source of the problem, but here it goes, maybe you know the magic answer.

I'm running this asp.net site with an AJAX updatePanel on my local machine, and everything works just fine, since it's where I developed it. Now, a few days ago, I uploaded the files to my web-host and assigned every single DataBase, and there is no error messages, even though it's still set to debug mode. There is a problem though, whenever I click an element which triggers my asp.net AJAX updatePanel to update, the whole site is updated(which it should not, only the Panel), and my jQuery's (document).ready is called every time as well.

Thank you for any help, I have no idea why this does not work online, nor' do I know why it does work on my local machine.

I have choosen not to upload the code, since I have no idea where the problem might lie, please feel free to ask for the code and I shall reply :)

Comment: Try using Fiddler:http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ and see if it helps identify where the problem might be.

Comment: A bit of code may help, as you said... Another thing you could do to test is put a button or autopostback element 'within' your update panel, instead of outside with a trigger. See if it still posts or calls back...

Comment: With further debugin' it seems that one of my JavaScript files are not loaded (it does work local though). In addition to my second one it should be called also with async postbacks, so I call it with "function pageLoad(){.." instead of "$(document).ready(function() {.."

I still dont know why this does not work with my webhost and only Local.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your web host either:

a) Is running .net 3.5
b) Has the Ajax extensions for .net 2.0 installed

...and that you are testing locally with the same?